How to customize the header in the miniframes outer theme?
I'd like to modify the color of the inactive sections and to underline the title of the currently active one when in the header of a beamer presentation using the miniframes outer theme. Is it possible to directly customize miniframes using things like \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{main}? I haven't found a key like title covered in head/foot or something along these lines, and I fail to understand how the relevant miniframes code works.
Am I required to redo a similar code to the one in miniframes?
MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}  
\useoutertheme{miniframes}  
\begin{document}  
\section{Section 1}  
\subsection{First subsection}  
\begin{frame}{Dummy frame}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}{Other dummy frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


You can change the section in head/foot template to add an underline like this:
\documentclass{beamer}  
\useoutertheme{miniframes}  

\colorlet{shadedsection}{red}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\underline{\insertsectionhead}}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{shadedsection!50!bg}\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other section}{\color{shadedsection!50!bg}\usebeamertemplate{mini frame in current section}}

\begin{document}  
\section{Section 1}  
\subsection{First subsection}  
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Dummy frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Dummy frame}
\end{frame}
\subsection{First subsection}  
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Dummy frame}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Other dummy frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


There had been a bug in beamer, which meant that the template for mini frame in other subsection was used instead of mini frame in other section. The code above needs beamer version v3.72 or later.
Until this is released, an updated file can be downloaded from
https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/main/base/beamerbasenavigation.sty and placed in the same folder as the presentation.
